# php converting number to other base by default?

Tags: php

i am writing a code in php where in i am passing a number to a function. but in the function,it defaultly converting to other base i guess. please find the code below.

```
 <?php
  function generate_alpha_num_id($x){
  echo $x;
    }
  generate_alpha_num_id(010100001);
 ?>
```

ideally, my output should be 10100001. but the code output is 2129921.

I am struggling to understand why is this happening. any help is much appricated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Because your number begins with a 0, it is interpreted in PHP as using a base 8 (octal) system.

Answer (score 0):

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):

> To use octal notation, precede the number with a 0 (zero). To use hexadecimal notation precede the number with 0x. To use binary notation precede the number with 0b.

PHP thinks it's doing you a favor by converting your number to an octal value.  Here's a way to solve your issue:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/fNOtR))

```
function generate_alpha_num_id($x){
  return 0+$x;  // add zero to convert strings to integers (effectively trimming leading zeros)
}
echo generate_alpha_num_id(010100001);  // send parameter as 2129921 base 8 (octal)

echo "\n---\n";

echo generate_alpha_num_id('010100001');  // send parameter as string to avoid octal interpretation
```

Output:

```
2129921
---
10100001
```

In the first function call, zero and the octal number are added together to generate an unchanged octal sum.

In the second function call, zero and the string-type number are added together.  PHP evaluates the string as an integer and adds it to zero, generating the sum effectively removes the leading zero(s).

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion):

> When a string is evaluated in a numeric context, the resulting value and type are determined as follows.
>
> If the string does not contain any of the characters '.', 'e', or 'E' and the numeric value fits into integer type limits (as defined by PHP_INT_MAX), the string will be evaluated as an integer. In all other cases it will be evaluated as a float.

To offer a few more ways to solve the problem, consider the following variations:

```
function generate_alpha_num_id($x){
    var_export(0+$x);
    echo "\n---\n";
    var_export((int)$x);
    echo "\n---\n";
    var_export((integer)$x);
    echo "\n---\n";
    var_export(1*$x);
    echo "\n---\n";
    var_export(intval($x));
    echo "\n---\n";
}
generate_alpha_num_id('010100001');  // send parameter as string to avoid octal interpretation
```

Output:

```
10100001
---
10100001
---
10100001
---
10100001
---
10100001
---
```